# Add "now" row to duration calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a query that calculates duration of an incident. However, it doesn't include the current time for the still "open" incidents. I am trying to figure out a way to add that to the below. This is running on Azure SQL 12.0.2000.8. Per the example, Incident 18 and 19 are closed (last record has StatusID<>1), so my current calculation is correct. However, Incident 20 is ongoing (last record has StatusId=1) and needs to calculate the time between the last update and now.

*Structure:*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncidentActions](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IncidentId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ActionDate] [DATETIMEOFFSET](7) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[IncidentActions] VALUES
( 51, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:39:27.8621563+00:00', N'This is a demo of the app ops incident management portal', 1 ), 
( 52, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:41:42.4306254+00:00', N'Superfast update we''re on it', 1 ), 
( 53, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:42:19.0766735+00:00', N'Found a workaround', 1 ), 
( 55, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:44:05.7958553+00:00', N'Suspending for now', 2 ), 
( 56, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:44:49.732564+00:00', N'No longer suspended', 1 ), 
( 57, 18, N'2020-03-10T13:45:09.8056202+00:00', N'All sorted', 3 ), 
( 58, 19, N'2020-03-11T14:47:05.6968653+00:00', N'This is just a test', 1 ), 
( 59, 19, N'2020-03-11T14:51:20.4522014+00:00', N'Found workaround and root cause, not yet fixed', 1 ), 
( 60, 19, N'2020-03-11T14:52:34.857061+00:00', N'Networking issues, updates suspended', 2 ), 
( 61, 19, N'2020-03-11T14:54:48.2262037+00:00', N'Network issue resolved, full functionality restored', 3 ), 
( 62, 20, N'2020-03-12T10:49:11.5595048+00:00', N'There is an ongoing issue', 1 ), 
( 63, 20, N'2020-03-12T11:29:37.9376805+00:00', N'This incident is ongoing....', 1 )
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncidentStatuses](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[IncidentStatuses] VALUES
( 1, N'OPEN' ), ( 2, N'SUSPENDED' ), ( 3, N'CLOSED' )
GO
```

*Query:*

```
WITH allActions
AS (SELECT IncidentId,
           ActionDate,
           IncidentStatuses.Description,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY ActionDate) AS rowNum
    FROM IncidentActions
    INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentStatuses ON IncidentStatuses.Id = IncidentActions.StatusId
    )
,actionPeriods
AS (SELECT firstAction.IncidentId,
          firstAction.Description StartStatus,
          secondAction.Description EndStatus,
          DATEDIFF(SECOND, firstAction.ActionDate, secondAction.ActionDate) SecondsElapsed
    FROM allActions firstAction
    INNER JOIN allActions secondAction ON firstAction.rowNum +1 = secondAction.rowNum --the next action
                                AND firstAction.IncidentId = secondAction.IncidentId --for the same incident
    )
SELECT 
    actionPeriods.IncidentId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN actionPeriods.StartStatus = 'OPEN' THEN actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN actionPeriods.StartStatus <> 'OPEN' THEN actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsInactive,
    SUM(actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed) SecondsElapsed
FROM actionPeriods
GROUP BY actionPeriods.IncidentId
GO
```

Comment: Use LAST_VALUE to check the last row's status. Hint: There's no need for a self-join over a ROW_NUMBER, use LEAD to get data from the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CTE is quit overkill. You could use tsql windowing functions. In this case the lag and or lead functions. I have added a sample code based on your tables.

```
select 
IncidentId, 
StatusId,actiondate , 
lag(actiondate) over (partition by incidentid order by incidentid, actiondate) as previousrow,
coalesce(
lead(actiondate) over (partition by incidentid order by incidentid, actiondate),
case 
    when (max(actiondate) over (partition by incidentid order by incidentid) = actiondate) and (statusid = 3) then actiondate 
    when (max(actiondate) over (partition by incidentid order by incidentid) = actiondate) and (statusid = 1) then convert([DATETIMEOFFSET](7),getdate())
end
) as nextrow
from 
    dbo.IncidentActions 
order by 
    IncidentId, ActionDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying LEAD instead of a self-join based on Row_number:

```
WITH allPeriods AS
 (
   SELECT IncidentId,
      Lead(ActionDate)     Over (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) AS ActionDate,
      Lead(st.Description) Over (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) AS StartStatus,
      st.Description AS EndStatus,

      CASE -- return NOW if the last row is "open" 
         WHEN Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) = 1
          AND StatusId = 1
         THEN getdate() 
         ELSE ActionDate
      END AS nextDate
   FROM IncidentActions AS act
   JOIN dbo.IncidentStatuses AS st
     ON st.Id = act.StatusId
 ),
elapsed AS
 ( SELECT *,
      DATEDIFF(SECOND, ActionDate, nextDate) AS SecondsElapsed
   FROM allPeriods
 )
SELECT
    IncidentId,
    Sum(CASE WHEN StartStatus =  'OPEN' THEN SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsActive,
    Sum(CASE WHEN StartStatus <> 'OPEN' THEN SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsInactive,
    Sum(SecondsElapsed) SecondsElapsed
FROM elapsed
WHERE ActionDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY IncidentId
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23e3c34fbf766fc0498dfcd4fab361c9)

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, the final version, courtesy of [Remko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5967455/remko)

```
WITH actionPeriods /* This one determines the elapsed time between actions */
AS (SELECT IncidentId,
       IncidentStatuses.Description StatusDesc,
       /* LAG(ActionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY IncidentId, ActionDate) AS previousrow, */
       DATEDIFF(SECOND,ActionDate,
        COALESCE(LEAD(ActionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY IncidentId, ActionDate), /* Lead gets the next action */
                CASE /* If the next aciton is NULL, then get either the current time for active, or the original time for closed */
                    WHEN (MAX(ActionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY IncidentId) = ActionDate) AND (StatusId = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.IncidentStatuses WHERE Description = 'CLOSED')) THEN ActionDate
                    WHEN (MAX(ActionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY IncidentId) = ActionDate) AND (StatusId <> (SELECT Id FROM dbo.IncidentStatuses WHERE Description = 'CLOSED')) THEN GETUTCDATE()
                END
               )
        ) SecondsElapsed
    FROM dbo.IncidentActions
    INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentStatuses ON IncidentStatuses.Id = IncidentActions.StatusId
    )
SELECT 
    actionPeriods.IncidentId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN actionPeriods.StatusDesc = 'OPEN' THEN actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsActive, /* This counts periods that are active */
    SUM(CASE WHEN actionPeriods.StatusDesc = 'SUSPENDED' THEN actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsInactive, /* This count periods that are inactive */
    SUM(CASE WHEN actionPeriods.StatusDesc IN ('OPEN','SUSPENDED') THEN actionPeriods.SecondsElapsed ELSE 0 END) SecondsElapsed /* We don't want periods that were CLOSED, as the ticket was not elapsing during that time */
FROM actionPeriods
GROUP BY actionPeriods.IncidentId
```

Comment: Just a side comment - temporal tables exist to help you with problems involving time tracking.  It does a chunk of the work for you for start/end time management.  You'd still need to compute "now" for active cases, but you could potentially get the other logic with less "other code" required.